# Receiving this error message: The method chargeFee() in the type Account is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class Testtesttest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        Account acct1, acct2;

        acct1 = new Account(1000, "Sally", 1111);
        acct2 = new Account(500, "Joe", 1112);

        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Initial Balance of Accounts:");
        System.out.println("Sally's balance is: " + fmt.format(acct1.getBalance()));
        System.out.println("Joe's balance is: " + fmt.format(acct2.getBalance()));
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");

        acct2.deposit(100);
        System.out.println("Joe" + " deposits $100.");

        System.out.println("Joe's New Balance is: " + fmt.format(acct2.getBalance()));

        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");

        acct1.withdraw(50);
        System.out.println("Sally" + " withdraws $50.");
        System.out.println("Sally's New Balance is: " + fmt.format(acct1.getBalance()));

        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("A fee of $10 will be charged to each account");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Sally's New Balance is: " + acct1.chargeFee(10));
        System.out.println("Joe's New Balance is: " + acct2.chargeFee(10));

        acct2.changeName("Joseph");
        System.out.println("Account 2's new name is " + "Joseph");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");

        System.out.println("Summary of Accounts: ");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(acct1);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(acct2);
    }
}
```

I'm really new to Java in general and without the chargeFee section, the code runs perfectly. Please help as I need to get this done for class and I just can't figure it out.

Comment: where is the function? show us the chargeFee function (in the account class).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you didn't make your account, you need to add the account number, balance, and name. (idk what your constructor page looks like since u only posted the driver). The reason your balance doesn't come up is because you didn't actually typed what Sally's and Joe's balance is. As for the error with your chargeFee, if you've left it alone, the reason why it doesn't work on your driver is because chargeFee is a void, adding a string to a void doesn't fit well. Also you shouldn't be retyping Joe's new name, that's what the toString is for.

Forgot to mention, take out 10 from chargeFee since in ur constructor, the code balance-= 10; does the math for you already.